# Python Regex with variable pattern, pattern length?

Tags: python, regex, basic-authentication

I am trying to develop a function that takes a name from a user, and attempts to match the name with a database of arbitrarily reserved usernames. The pattern(the reserved names) is variable length, and the username can be anything. I'm trying to prevent users from taking usernames that are reserved basically, but the usernames are of different lengths. People will also try and make a similar username, so it has to match those as well which is where it gets difficult.

For an example if I want Golden Retriever to be a reserved username. I also want Goolden Reettreever to be reserved because they are obviously trying to make a name that is reserved.

`

```
import re
username = "Stephen Jobless".lower()
reserved_name = "Steve Jobs".lower()
def regex_scour(reserved_name):
    first_name, last_name  = reserved_name.split()[0], reserved_name.split()[1]
    
    #loop through username replacing one character with wildcard, returns match. Can be adjusted depending on how strict we want to
    for i in range(len(first_name)):
        sliced_name= first_name.replace(first_name[i], '') 
        pattern = re.compile(f"{sliced_name[:i]}.*{sliced_name[i:]}") 
        match = re.search(pattern, username)
        sliced_name = first_name
        try:
            match = match.group()
        except AttributeError:
            continue

        return match

    for i in range(len(last_name)):
        sliced_name= last_name.replace(last_name[i], '')
        pattern = re.compile(f".*{sliced_name[:i]}.*{sliced_name[i:]}.*")
        match = re.search(pattern, username)
        sliced_name = last_name
        try:
            match = match.group()
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        if match != None:
            return match
        else:
            return match
print(regex_scour(reserved_name))
```

`
Here is my very rough and unrefined code for the regex portion that isn't working particulary well. Assume the reserved name is two words seperated by whitespace.

I have been trying to make a function using regex,difflib sequencematcher, and groupby to remove duplicate consecutive characters and it kinda works by using a for loop to remove a character and replace it with a wildcard. But it is slow, complicated, and I'm just wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Except for using the `in` function from a list of all reserved usernames and their variants, you probably could consider string similarity algorithms which can give a score to every string input and determine how similar it is to one of your keyword by a certain threshold (for example 70%). But I don't think it will prevent all variants, as you can get very creative with usernames.